# FileReader skipping every other line from CSV comma delimitted file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, filereader

Why is this code skipping every other line in the CSV sheet, which has only 3 columns?

```
public void loadFile(String fileName) {
    try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\src\\" + fileName + "", StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {

        while (csvReader.readLine() != null) {

            String[] data = csvReader.readLine().split(",", 3);
            String sku = data[0];
            String title = data[1];
            double price = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
            Product newProduct = new Product(sku, title, price);
            newProduct.setProducts(newProduct);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not load file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `readLine` twice for each iteration.

Comment: I suspected it was the point raised by iota below, but you are are 100% correct. The readline is being called once as the while loop argument, and again in the execution of it. Well spotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `readLine`, it reads a line and moves to the next line. You need to store the line read.

```
String line;
while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = line.split(",", 3);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Solved using your suggestion. I incorrectly assumed that the `while (csvReader.readLine() != null)` argument would not be executed, and only be used as a qualifier. But the `readLine` in both places was forcing a line to be skipped.